# SQL Database how to link primary and foreign key before inserting

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

Designing my first SQL database with Postgresql.

Here is my design so far:

[image]

This is how the Data comes to the backend :

```
   "questions": [
       {
           "name": "What is Jhons's last name?",
           "category": "Personal",
           "explanation": "Just the way it is",
           "options": [
               {
                   "name": "James",
                   "correct": false
               },
               {
                   "name": "Ron",
                   "correct": true
               },
               {
                   "name": "Chris",
                   "correct": false
               },
               {
                   "name": "Tom",
                   "correct": false
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "name": "What is John's first name?",
           "category": "Personal",
           "explanation": "Just the way it is 2",
           "options": [
               {
                   "name": "John",
                   "correct": true
               },
               {
                   "name": "Rohn",
                   "correct": false
               },
               {
                   "name": "Heimer",
                   "correct": false
               },
               {
                   "name": "Eric",
                   "correct": false
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

**What i am trying to do:**

I want to insert each Question into it's Questions table.

Then I want to insert each Options object into it's Options Table.

I want to be able to link each option to each questionId primary key (like shown in the picture).

**My issue/question:**

How can I get the Question ID before inserting, to be able to use that is the options foreign key. It is my understanding that the ID is only created once the row is inserted. **Do I need to create my own ID for the question, so i can insert the Options with that created ID?**

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the question first before you can insert options.  One method is to use CTEs:

```
with q as (
      insert into questions ( . . . )
          values ( . . . )
          returning *
     )
insert into questionoptions (questionid, . . . )
    select q.questionid, . . .
    from q;
```

Note two changes that I made to the naming.  The `options` table is called `questionoptions` because the options are for a question.  Also, the primary key and the foreign key have the same name -- `questionid` -- so the code is self documentating.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that table `Questions` is automatically populating `id` column with a serial number:

```
DECLARE _question_id integer;
...
INSERT INTO Questions (...) VALUES (...) RETURNING id INTO _question_id;
...
INSERT INTO Options (..., questionId) VALUES (..., _question_id);
```

More info about **RETURNING** clause: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-insert.html

Comment: No need for PL/pgSQL

Comment: So i would INSERT first the question, then after that operation, I get the ID as a returned variable that I can store. And then directly afterwards, I make the options databse operation, which I can then use the previous variable in that statement?

Answer (score 1):

If the ID is generated through an identity (or serial) column, then you can use [lastval()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html):

```
insert into questions (...) values (...);
insert into options(question_id, ...) values (lastval(), ...);
```

Comment: interesting, are these seperate database operations, or in the same SQL statement?

Comment: @CevinThomas: those are two INSERT statements which you would typically run in a single transaction

Comment: interesting, never thought about that. Only been doing SQL for a few days, but I will definitely look into that now. Thank you so much for your time!